# MonoTouch iPhone orientations are not matched pairs

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, orientation, warnings, monodevelop

I'm just starting out with MonoTouch and have just written the usual Hello World type app that does very little. I'm trying to get a completely clean build with no errors or warnings.

I am getting the warning:

```
Info.plist: Warning: Supported iPhone orientations are not matched pairs
```

I know why - it's because Portrait upside down is not selected. But that's the recommendation from Apple (and in fact the MonoTouch default!) so why give a warning.

How do I get rid of this warning? (without adding upside down, obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Apple recommend this behaviour for the iPhone but not for the iPad. It's likely that the addin does not make the distinction and warn for every case.

> How do I get rid of this warning?

I do not think you can (presently). However it's a warning (not an error) so it will not cause any issue with your build.

If it really bother you I suggest you to fill an enhancement [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with Xamarin (under MonoDevelop, iPhone addin).

Comment: Really no way to stop the warning? I am trailing MonoTouch to decide if our company should start using it. So you are saying everyone developing an iPhone project with the latest MonoTouch has to put up with a warning?! It really makes you worry if they can't even get that right, what the rest of it is like. Personally I would never ship a product with a warning!

Comment: MonoTouch have agreed to fix this in their next version :)